# scrollIntoView() preventing other listeners from triggering

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

I am using `scrollIntoView()` on an event target to ensure it is visible in its parent which has `overflow: scroll`, this is mainly for accessibility reasons.

My problem is that I also have click events associated with this element and when a click event also fires the focus `e.target.scrollIntoView()` is preventing other events from firing.

This is my current example:
http://jsfiddle.net/omhuorpr/

```
require([
    "dojo/query",
    "dojo/on"
], function(query, on){

    var el = query('#someElement');

    el.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("clicked");
    });

    el.on('focus', function(e){
        console.log("focus");
        e.target.scrollIntoView();
    });

});
```

If you click on the element and check the console it will only fire the focus, if you re-click it then fires the click. Ideally I want to fire both at the same time or just the click.

A simple fix that works is to move this process to the end of the execution stack via a timeout however ideally I want to find out why `scrollIntoView()` is preventing other events from firing.

Comment: Weird aside: when I click the `a` in your fiddle, it scrolls the jsfiddle menu bar mostly off the top of my screen, and I can't scroll back, even after refreshing the page! Does that happen for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `focus` event fires on mouse down, and the `click` event fires on mouse up. If the element has scrolled so that the mouse pointer is no longer over the element by the time you release the button, the `click` event won't fire. However, if the mouse pointer is still over the element after the scroll, the `click` *will* fire.

If you increase the font size in your fiddle and click near the top, you'll see the `click` fire. If you click near the bottom and the element scrolls out from under the pointer, the `click` event won't fire. E.g.

```
#someElement {
    font-size:80px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/omhuorpr/1/